# C# socket connection keeps sending data after disconnect and close

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a "start" and "stop" button. When clicking the start button, a new socket is created and a connection is made. When clicking the stop button the socket is shutdown, disconnected, closed and disposed to make sure it is completely gone.
At least, that's what I thought: when clicking start after stopping the connection, a new socket is made etc. but as soon as I send data, the data is sent x amount of times I had created a socket (thus, x amount of times I had clicked the start button).
This is the code for the start:

```
soc = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);  // Socket soc; is declared at class-level
        System.Net.IPAddress ipAdd = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(IP);
        System.Net.IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAdd, port);

        try
        {
            soc.Connect(remoteEP);
            soc.Send(jsonSettings);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not connect to socket");
        }
```

And this is the stop code:

```
if (soc != null)
        {
            soc.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            soc.Disconnect(false);
            soc.Close();
            soc.Dispose();
        }
```

This is used within a `VSTO PowerPoint add-in` application if this could cause any additional specialties, when the connection is made I'm sending string data to a Python server listening to this port. Each time a connection is closed, the Python server will get out of it's listen-for-data loop and get back in it's waiting for connection state (for the multiple start/stop connections).

Code for sending data:

```
// this is called each time the user goes to another slide in the PowerPoint presentation
byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringValue); 
soc.Send(byData);
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong why the socket connections somehow keep on living and sending data even though I disconnected and closed them?

Answer (score 1):

The observed behavior is the whole point and desired outcome from clean shutdown.  From the MSDN page for `Socket.Shutdown()`:

> When using a connection-oriented Socket, always call the Shutdown method before closing the `Socket`. **This ensures that all data is sent and received on the connected socket before it is closed.**

The call to `Shutdown()` prevents your application from queuing  additional outgoing data, it does not stop the network stack from sending data already buffered.

Comment: Then why does the socket still send data _after_ the socket has been disconnected, shut down and disposed? There is no more data in it's buffer at that point so it shouldn't be sending anything as the socket is closed and released, yet when I want to send data afterwards on an entirely new socket, the previous socket(s) send the data as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a stream socket, how about declaring a network stream for your socket like this:

```
NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(soc);
```

Then flushing this after each send (and before closing the socket):

```
stream.Flush();
```

Also ensure you turn off Nagle's algorithm when you create the socket - it will prevent batching up items on the socket:

```
soc.NoDelay = true;
```